# How to use JsonIgnore in Spring Boot to stop infinite loop?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a many to many relationship in my project between User and a Product. A User can have many products and a Product can be owned by many Users.

User.java

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable( name = "user_product",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"))
    private List<Product> listOfProductsForUser;
```

Product.java

```
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "listOfProductsForUser")
    private List<User> listOfUsersForProduct;
```

In my controller, I have a path that gets me all the users and the nested products associated with the user like this.

```
[
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "userName": "Fido",
        "age": 3,
        "listOfProductsForUser": [
            {
                "productId": 1,
                "productName": "tooth brush",
            },
            {
                "productId": 2,
                "productName": "potatoes",
            },
            {
                "productId": 3,
                "productName": "carrot",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "userId": 2,
        "userName": "David",
        "age": 12,
        "listOfProductsForUser": [
            {
                "productId": 6,
                "productName": "oranges",
            },
            {
                "productId": 7,
                "productName": "tomatoes",
            },
            {
                "productId": 6,
                "productName": "buns",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is fine but I now want to get all products which should have nested users (to get all products and see which users are using them).
While attempting to do this I run into a recursive problem and I have used JsonIgnore on the product.java's `listOfProductsForUser` variable as shown above to stop the recursion. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If `@JsonIgnore` doesn't meet your needs, you may want to look at `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of ways to deal with this bi-directional relationship issue. I think `@JsonIdentityInfo` is the best way in your case.

What you need to do is change your `User` and `Product` class as follows.

```
//other annotations
@JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
  property = "userId")
public class User {
    // your code
}
```

```
//other annotations
@JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
  property = "productId")
public class Product {
    // your code
}
```

*Note: For more info [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion)*

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```java
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable( name = "user_product",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"))
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Product> listOfProductsForUser;
```

```java
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "listOfProductsForUser")

@JsonBackReference
private List<User> listOfUsersForProduct;
```

These two annotations ([@JsonManagedReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonManagedReference.html) and [@JsonBackReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html)) avoid infinite recursion.

---

I misunderstood the question. Both `listOfUsersForProduct` and `listOfProductsForUser`should be present in the JSON. The previous solution omits `listOfUsersForProduct`. To have both you need to use `@JsonIdentityInfo` as @ray already suggested:

```java
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "userId")
public class User { }
```

```java
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "productId")
public class Product { }
```

Comment: It stops the recursion but I still can not get the array of User `listOfUsersForProduct` when I get all the products.

Comment: That is in fact weird. Try swapping the annotations. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I swapped it. Now it flipped. I can now access the list of Users through `listOfUsersForProduct ` array but I cannot get the list of Products through `listOfProductsForUser ` when I getAll from the UserRepository.

Comment: Wait, do you want to have both `listOfUsersForProduct` and `listOfProductsForUser`? In that case, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yes sir. Is it possible?

Comment: I've updated my answer. It is basically what @ray already suggested, so kudos to him. If it actually works accept and upvote his answer and upvote mine ;)

Comment: Thank you good sir.

Comment: You are welcome ;)